# iPhone 4S won't power off

Tags: iphone

I powered off my iPhone ([sample instructions](http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonehowtos/qt/turn_off_iphone.htm)). I see the progress wheel for a few seconds after holding down the power button and sliding the 'slide to power off' and then I see the silver Apple logo as if it powered on immediately.

Is this a reset and not a power off? Did this before going to sleep and woke up with a dead battery.

I've struggled with low battery life and did the full replacment of operating system. If I have to go through that again, I'll get a new phone.

Version: 6.1.2

Comment: This sure sounds like a hardware problem, but before seeking support from AppleCare, you might look over the computer that performed the restore and see what the log file has for the restore event. If you can edit in more details on how you went about replacing the OS and what computer you might have with iTunes installed, you might be able to fix this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates a hardware problem with your phone. [Contact AppleCare](http://apple.com/support), or make a Genius Bar reservation at your [local Apple Store](http://apple.com/retail)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and powered it down will plugged in.

Tried restarting the phone and then powering down, but that didn't help.

Seems like the only way I can power this phone off is to plug it into a charger.

Comment: maybe a different battery won't have the fault. perhaps you can try swapping battery with somebody or at a shop where they have them to try. perhaps you can hand them $10  or perhaps they'll do it free of charge. just try the battery from one of their show devices and see if it works.